# i have a problem with player movment while jumping

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

the only problem that i face that the player only jump when they build momentum and i dont want that i want player jump by pressing space while standing or moving i tried velocity.y=jumphight which doesnt work too

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovment : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    public CharacterController controller;
    public float speed = 12f;
    public float gravity = -9.81f;
    Vector3 velocity;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;
    bool isGrounded;
    public float JumpHight = 3f;


    void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);
        if(isGrounded && velocity.y<0)
        {
            controller.slopeLimit = 45.0f;
            velocity.y = -2f;//when player is grounded it just put some gravity to him all the time
        }
        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");//moves left and right
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");//moves up and down
        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;
        controller.Move(move*speed*Time.deltaTime);
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && controller.isGrounded)
        {


            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(JumpHight * -2f * gravity);
        }
        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);




    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're adding gravity yourself here in the code, the engine should be able to do that for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Vector3 velocity;
public float gravity = -9.82f;
public float JumpHeight = 3f;

if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")
{
  velocity.y = Matf.Sqrt(JumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
}
```

You could also do what the other person said, the reason this person's line of code might not have worked it due to how weak it is. Here is an updated version of said code.

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.up * 10f ,ForceMode.Impulse);
```

The reason I am using the * is to increase the "up" variable since it means Vector3(0f, 1f, 0f); and using the ForceMode.Impulse to make it more volatile and stronger.

Hope this code helps you in your game making,
Kind Regards. SB

Comment: Ok so I got a problem im using chracter controller so I need to make rigidbody to assign the code that you wrote which i don't need but thx for the help . What I found is when I remove dection of ground from jump code it solves my problem but it opens another one where if the player  press jump repeatedly it  can make him fly so how can I solve it

Comment: You can either check to see if the player is grounded, like in your code above. If(Input.GetKeyDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
{

}

If this does not work then something is wrong with your boolean and I would recommend reviewing it

Still having problems?
Use this revised version of your code.

https://shrib.com/?v=nc#Klipspringer_p62X95

Comment: Thank you for accepting my Answer! ~~ Kind Regards, SB

Answer (score 1):

you could use an addforce on the rigidbody with a ForceMode force , and if you don't want your physic depending on the fps use FixedUpdate instead of update

```
   GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.up,ForceMode.Force);
```

Comment: im using character controller not rigidbody so i dont think it is going to work

Comment: oh right sorry, then you might increase the position vertically, but seen that you want to add gravity and stuff you might be better off using a rigidbody if you don't really need a character controller